# Why is the domain of a composition of functions an intersection and not a union?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm studying the composition of functions from the [University of Toronto Pre-calculus website](https://www.math.toronto.edu/preparing-for-calculus/4_functions/we_2_composition.html).

The instructions for determining the domain of a composition is as follows:

> $(f \circ g)(x)$ is defined when $g(x)$ and $f(g(x))$ are defined! So when determining the domain of a composition of functions, take the domain of the inner function, and continue outwards to see if you need to remove any more $x$-values. I.e., $domain((f\circ g)(x)) = domain(g(x)) \cap domain(f(g(x)))$.

My question: why is the domain of a composition of function the *intersection* of the constituent functions? Shouldn't it be the union? Doesn't taking the intersection mean that if one function has a restriction not shared by the other, it won't apply to the composition? And wouldn't that be a bad thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the intersection of the domains (the non-restricted inputs), rather than the intersection of the restrictions!

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! Even when I think I've figured it out, I'm never quite sure until somebody agrees with me

Comment: I know that feeling rather well!

Answer (score 0):

Ah, nevermind. I think I see my error now.

I was thinking about the domain as the set of values that are to be excluded, rather than the set of values that are to be allowed.

Comment: Just as I answered. ;)

Comment: Thank you :) I'll accept your answer in 5 minutes, once the site allows me